# Stopping a button when conditions are not met

Tags: swift

Using Swift I'm trying to stop a button from executing if the user input is not correct? A hard coded login screen of such. Is any one able to help?

```
@IBOutlet weak var errorMessage: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var user_name: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!


@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if  user_name.text != "admin" {

        errorMessage.text = "Incorrect username or password"
        print(errorMessage)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return` after showing the `errorMessage` – it will exit the function immediately:

```
@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
  if user_name.text != "admin" {
    errorMessage.text = "Incorrect username or password"
    print(errorMessage)
    return
  }
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the sender from Any to UIButton and disable it.

```
@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if  user_name.text != "admin" {
        errorMessage.text = "Incorrect username or password"
        print(errorMessage)
        sender.isEnabled = false
   }
}
```